# Enumerate all superincreasing subsequences

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

A sequence of positive real numbers **S1, S2, S3, …, SN** is called a superincreasing sequence if every element of the sequence is greater than the sum of all the previous elements in the sequence. E.g: 1, 3, 6, 13, 27, 52.

Given a sorted list **A**, I want to iterate over all combinations of **A**, which are superincreasing.

How example:

> A = [28, 34, 44, 60, 71, 150, 167, 212, 230, 239, 415, 431, 434, 559,
> 688]

Valid examples of subsequences:

```
34, 44, 239, 434
34, 212, 434, 688
```

Here is a simple brute force example:

```
def is_superincreasing(seq):
 total = 0
 test = True
 for n in seq:
    if n <= total:
        test = False
        break
    total += n
 return test

def combinations(A):
    N = len(A)
    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(A[j])
        if is_superincreasing(combo):
         yield combo
```

I'd like to know if there is a better algorithm than O(2^n).

Comment: 1. What's a "superincreasing combination of A"?  2.  What is your question?  What approaches have you already considered?  Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @D.W., thanks! I've updated the question.

Comment: What is a "combination of A"?  Do you mean "subsequence"?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: Also, note that if $A = \{1,2,4,8,...,2^k,...,2^n\}$ you can't do better than $\Omega(2^n)$.  However, like @D.W. says, I believe that dynamic programming and memoization will give you optimal results.

Comment: By "combinations of A", do you mean "subsets of A"?

Comment: Note that a1 >= a0, a2 >= 2a0, a3 >= 4a0, a4 >= 8 a0 etc. which will often make this fast. You might want to look at superincreasing sequences with no superincreasing subsequences.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution in terms of complexity, because of duplicate summation operations with further elements, but much better in the general case.

```
def superincreasing_combinations(g):
  ln = len(g) - 1
  operate = {}
  ret = set()

  for i, e in enumerate(g):
    operate[(e,)] = (i, e)

  while operate:
    o, v = operate.popitem()
    last_index, sumo = v

    while last_index < ln:
     last_index += 1
     next = g[last_index]
     if next > sumo:
      operate[(*o, next)] = (last_index, sumo + next)

    ret.add(o)
  return ret
```

Comment: We're not a coding site, and we discourage code-only answers.  Instead, we're looking for ideas, concise pseudocode, algorithms, explanations, and/or proof of correctness.